# Cordova windows 8 phone WNS push notification and app release process with details

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I am developing windows phone application using cordova. I need to implement push notification in this application. now i am using the below plugin to push notification.
https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

I have created a windows developer account and register the app in this account. Also created a client Id, client secret in Live Services site. I need to clear explanation for adding app identity in the windows application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First add this plugin  https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

add this in script file.

```
if(deviceID == "undefined" || deviceID == null || deviceID == "null"){
            pushNotificationVariable = window.plugins.pushNotification;
            var platform = device.platform;

            switch(platform){
                case 'iOS':
                    pushNotificationVariable.register(tokenHandler,errorHandler,{ "badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});
                break;
                case 'Android':
                    pushNotificationVariable.register(successHandler,errorHandler,{"senderID":"643203326229","ecb":"onNotification"});
                break;
                case 'Win32NT':
                    var channelName = "PUSHChannel";
                    pushNotificationVariable.register(channelHandler, errorHandler, { "channelName": channelName, "ecb": "onNotificationWP8", "uccb": "channelUriHandler", "errcb": "jsonErrorHandler" });
                break;
                default:
                    window.localStorage.setItem("DeviceID",device.uuid);
                break;
            }

        }
```

this code will return the ChannelURI after that u send that ChannelURI to Service,So that they can able to send the Push to windows phone.

[Try this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx)

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx)

Add this in Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        try
        {
            if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString["NavigatedFrom"] == "Toast Notification") // this is set on the server
            {
                string navigatedString = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["NavigatedFrom"];
                this.CordovaView.StartPageUri = new Uri("//www/index.html#navstring=" + navigatedString, UriKind.Relative);
            }
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
        {
        }
    }
```

call the angularjs function from javscript

```
function ajaxResultPost(data, type, res) {
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("MainWrap")).scope();
scope.$apply(function () {
scope.updateCustomRequest(data, type, res);
});
}
```

if u want call the javascript function from c# then try this

```
this.CordovaView.Browser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "yourJavascriptFunction(); " });
```

How to call JavaScript from C# – Cordova/PhoneGap

https://cordovablogsblogs.wordpress.com/2015/07/10/how-to-call-javascript-from-c-cordovaphonegap/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Now i am getting notification. I need to navigate a corresponding page on clicking a notification. Please help me. thanks.

Comment: I already referred this solution. But my issue is push notification received from different modules. when i am using this code the url was navigated. But my contents are not loading because the contents are loaded from angularJs function. I need to know how to call the angularjs function before the navigation.